# Create a getMethod using serverless framework

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless-framework

I use the serverless framework.
I use AWS API GateWay.
I would like to create an API to enter this command at the terminal and receive the parameter "name" and the parameter "type".

```
$ mkdir test-serverless
$ cd test-serverless
$ sls create --template aws-nodejs --name test
$ vi serverless.yml
$cat serverless.yml
service:test
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs6.10
  region: ap-northeast-1

functions:
 testfunc:
   handler: handler.func
   events:
     - http:
         path: testpath
         method: get
         request:
             querystrings:
               name: true
               type: true
             headers:
               Accept: application/json

$  sls deploy -v
```

With this command, the API was created successfully.
However, none of the parameters were set.
As a result, I set the parameters manually in the AWS console.
But wait for correct knowledge.
As a result, is not it possible to eliminate manual input with the serverless framework?
Reflecting the setting of parameters in API GateWay If anyone knows how to write yml, please let me know.

I want to easily hit the API with curl.

```
$ curl http://url.com/para?name=test&type=test
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the correct identation:

```
functions:
  testfunc:
    handler: handler.func
    events:
      - http:
          path: testpath
          method: get
          request:
            querystrings:
              name: true
              type: true
            headers:
              Accept: application/json
```